# Cross-platform script to install Node + NPM + Grunt?

Tags: node.js, build, npm, integration

At our office, we are currently integrating a Node/NPM/Grunt stack into an environment that has been primarily driven by Maven/Nexus.

As part of our continuous integration setup, we need a way to ensure that machines which check out our projects have the appropriate binaries to run our builds.

I've done some looking on the internet but cannot find any cross-platform (e.g. Ant, Make, etc.) build scripts that would support installing Node, NPM, and Grunt on any system. Does something like this exist?